# Windows batch scripting: use absolute path with spaces to run terminal as admin

Tags: windows, command-line, terminal, batch-file

I have an issue when using absolute path in batch script.

**Script Code:**

`powershell -c start -verb runas cmd '/c start cd "%~dp0%SomeScript.bat"'`

> **%~dp0%** : absolute path to the script

I want to start the terminal as an Administrator, Hence I can use another script ready to use.

The code works at some point, but it prompts to open the terminal, even the absolute path in the Windows prompt is correct, then I get an error:

```
Cannot find the path specified.
```

I searched all over the internet, and couldn't find a solution.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It looks like you’re trying to `cd` *to **the batch file**,*  rather than to the directory that contains it.

Comment: The problem is, if I try anything, I always get an error, that the path is not recognized as an internal or external command, Because it only sees the space in path, and I need to have the absolute path, because I will be running this script on multiple devices.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `cd` from your batch:

`powershell -c start -verb runas cmd '/c start "%~dp0%SomeScript.bat"'`

In the example below, the absolute path is `C:\Users\User\Desktop`, your command will be translated as:
`C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe  /K cd  C:\Users\User\Desktop\SomeScript.bat`

This way it will not work unless you remove the command `cd` and it will be like:
`C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe  /K C:\Users\User\Desktop\SomeScript.bat`

Comment: I tried your suggestion, and it still does not work. I get the error, where the absolute path has spaces, the error is (example that we have an absolute directory E:Some Stuff\Script.bat), that windows can not fint E:Some.